# Not getting my Roles from my SQL Server database through C#

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server, asp.net-mvc

I'm trying to build a application that validates your login with Windows via the Logon User Dll Import function. I have it working, but now I would like to ADD the ability for the user to be authenticated over my SQL database and given a Role. For example, user logins and receives role from SQL  and gets authorized by logon user. That role is Administrator,Management,User in the order of importance.  Not really sure what is wrong. Any help would be appreciated.

Here is my C# Code

```
FormsAuthentication.Initialize();
string roles = string.Empty;
var conn = @"Data Source = localhost;Initial Catalog=web";

using (var con = new SqlConnection(conn))
{
    using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("Get_User_Role"))
    {
        cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Username", btnLogin);

        cmd.Connection = con;

        con.Open();

        SqlDataReader reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();
        reader.Read();
        roles = reader["Roles"].ToString();
        con.Close();
    }
}
```

Here is my `web.config`:

```
<authentication mode="Forms">
      <forms loginUrl="login.aspx" name=".ASPXAUTH" protection="All" path="/" defaultUrl="Default.aspx" timeout="30" ></forms>
</authentication>
<authorization>
      <deny users="?"/>
      <allow roles="Administrators, Managers,Users"/>
      <allow users="*"/> <!-- might have to delete this to work, which is ok. Better to have and not need then to need and not have. -->
</authorization>
```

Here is my button login from ASP

```
<asp:Button ID="btnLogin" runat="server" width="315px" Cssclass="btn" 
            onclick="btnLogin_Click" Text="Login" ></asp:Button>
```

I run it and it stops at `con.Open` saying incorrect username.

I also was told I needed to add a list for either Administrator, Manager, User. I shouldn't haft too with `roles=reader["Roles"].ToString();` right?

Comment: It looks like you have a problem with your connection string  [ConnectionString](https://www.connectionstrings.com/sql-server/) 
/
[More Details](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/data/adonet/connection-string-syntax)

Comment: We need the schema of the table as well.

Comment: @JonathanAlfaro i'll edit it right now. Should I include the LOGON User code also? I made a Stored Procedure so that it doesn't access the tables directly. Need to see the stored procedure schema?

Comment: What I am concerned about is the "reader["Roles"]" is this a column with CSV?

Comment: Also we do not need to see the user or password.... but are you sure you are passing the correct user and password? Also just to confirm you are using a Microsoft SQL Database?

Comment: @JonathanAlfaro Yes, I'm using SQLServer 2018, VS 2019 Developers Edition, from the reader part, I'm told that it allows C# to read the roles without having to specificy with a list But I could be wrong.

Comment: In the text it says "Administrator, Manager, User" but in the web.config it says "Administrators, Managers,Users" (i.e. plurals). I guess it's just a typo in the text.

Comment: @AndrewMorton good catch, I'll change that now. I didn't even notice that

Comment: @MatheusDasuke Your suggestion was correct for the Conn problem. Now, I have a SQLDataRead problem and I'm sure that has to do with my Roles and what not. If you could click on the question answered, I can then mark it as such and ask the new question please.

Comment: @Airizzo Can you show the error you're getting?

Comment: What's the code of stored procedure? I'm a little concerned about your design: you are mixing system logon with sql server table for roles... I'd choose one way or the other. Windows users can be organized in Groups, without having to relate on database. On the other hand, there are plenty of solution for full database based authentication/authorization (see ASP.NET Identity).

Comment: @ClaudioValerio Unfortunately, we can assign the roles through windows since that is headed by our IT department and they don't feel the need to give EVERYONE Admin roles who we deem fit to have them. So our workaround was this. We wanted to make sure that whoever accessed was a employee, and that we could assign the roles ourselves so our IT didn't have the extra work.

Comment: Also, check about authentication mode "Windows"...

Comment: @MatheusDasuke System.ArgumentException: 'No mapping exists from object type System.Web.UI.WebControls.Button to a known managed provider native type.'
 is my new error. I'm sure it's with the roles and what not. I think I'm going to haft to make a arraylist and get it that way.

Comment: `cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Username", btnLogin);` is wrong. You probably have some Textbox on your form (`txtUsername` perheaps?), so correct line would be `cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Username", txtUsername.Text);`

Comment: @ClaudioValerio awesome! Thank you!

Comment: @Airizzo Just so you know: [AddWithValue is Evil](http://www.dbdelta.com/addwithvalue-is-evil/), [AddWithValue is evil!](http://chrisrickard.blogspot.com/2007/06/addwithvalue-is-evil.html), and [Can we stop using AddWithValue() already?](https://blogs.msmvps.com/jcoehoorn/blog/2014/05/12/can-we-stop-using-addwithvalue-already/).

Comment: @AndrewMorton How would you write it since that's how it checks against a username when you hit login? You can't hard code the info in it or what's the point?

Comment: @Airizzo All those articles show better alternatives.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I run it and it stops at con.Open saying incorrect username.

You have a problem with your connection string, check the links below:

[Microsoft Documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/data/adonet/connection-string-syntax)

[Examples](https://www.connectionstrings.com/sql-server/)

```
FormsAuthentication.Initialize();
string roles = string.Empty;
var conn = @"Data Source = localhost;Initial Catalog=web"; // Here your problem

using (var con = new SqlConnection(conn))
{
    using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("Get_User_Role"))
    {
        cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Username", btnLogin);

        cmd.Connection = con;

        con.Open();

        SqlDataReader reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();
        reader.Read();
        roles = reader["Roles"].ToString();
        con.Close();
    }
}
```

Comment: Yes, correct syntax was ```var conn = @"Server=MyserverHeret;Database=MyDatabaseHere;Trusted_Connection=True;";``` This lets me get to my server. Thank you